# Height Of Table Change when Rows Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a Table with number of Rows that i want to click on Rows then slide down the hidden rows. the problem is i have some empty Space under of each rows.is there a way to delete this empty space and add this only when each row clicked?
Here is my Snippet :

```js
var clicked=true;
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"top": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"top": "-25px"});
    }
});
```

```css
.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" style="border:1px solid #000;">
<tr class="one"> <td>HELLO WORLD</td></tr>
<tr class="two"><td>THIS IS HIDE TEXT</td></tr>
<tr class="one"> <td>HELLO WORLD</td></tr>
<tr class="two"><td>THIS IS HIDE TEXT</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always resort to flex-box layout.
Here is a kind of a hackish solution to your problem setting dispaly: flex on the table and display:block on the tr. now transitioning the height is np...

EDIT: Updated code to work for each line separately

```js
$(".one").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).next().height()==0) {
    clicked = false;
    $(this).next().css({
      "top": 0,
      "height": "25px"
    });
  } else {
    clicked = true;
    $(this).next().css({
      "top": "-25px",
      "height": "0"
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  display: flex;
}
tr {
  display: block
}
.one {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.two {
  height:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: allt 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" style="border:1px solid #000;">
  <tr class="one">
    <td>HELLO WORLD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>THIS IS HIDE TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>HELLO WORLD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>THIS IS HIDE TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. is there a way to show each hidden row Separately when click on each row?

Answer (score 1):

Simply substitute all javascript with this:

```
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

for your javascript part: https://jsfiddle.net/1p8wut0k/1/

`.next()` finds the immediate sibling

`.toggle()` changes it from hide/show (innately knows). You can also add a slight fade effect by putting numbers into it.